# Pangram Checker not working

Tags: java, pangram

This the code I have been using but it is working for strings which are not pangram but not the other way. Also for the  strings which have duplicate.

```
int i;
char l,ch;
String s="";
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
s=sc.next();
s=s.trim();
int c=0;
s=s.toLowerCase();
for (l='a';l<='z';l++) {
  for(i=0;i<s.length();i++) {
    ch=s.charAt(i);
    if(ch==l) {
      c++;
    }
  }
  if(c==0)
    break;
  else {
    c=0;
    continue;
  }
}
if(l=='z')
  System.out.println("pangram");
else
  System.out.println("not pangram");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're checking if `l` is equal to `z` after the loop.
If every letter except `z` is present in the sentence then you'd get a false positive since `l` will equal `z`.

Here you increment `l` for each loop:

```
for (l='a'; l<='z'; l++)
```

After the last loop (when `l` equals `z`) `l` will be incremented one more time.

What you need to do is to check if `l` is greater than `z`.

```
if (l > 'z')
  System.out.println("pangram");
...
```

**Edit**

`sc.next()` will return a string to the next token. (Line ending or whitespace)
If you input `We promptly judged antique ivory buckles for the next prize` `s` will only contain `We` since a space will be regarded as an "ending token" for `next()`. You need to use `sc.nextLine()` instead.

Comment: it is still not working. My test case is "We promptly judged antique ivory buckles for the next prize".This is a pangram string but my program is showing not pangram.

Comment: That's probably because you are using `sc.next()` instead of `sc.nextLine()`. `next()` will return a string to the next token which in this case is a whitespace character. So `s` will equal `We` and nothing else. Use `nextLine()` instead.